# Are there any jquery scripts that can do a Deviantart style drag and drop down?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, drop-down-menu, organizer

I'm incredibly impressed by the favoriting system built into Deviantart. I'd link to a demo but you have to be logged into deviantart to see it. So I'll describe it.

Basically it's a div or something that exists at the top of the page hidden. When you grab a picture (thumbnail or full size) and drag it toward the top of the screen, the div apears and slides down with a list of folders in it. The folders are horizontal (left to right). You just drop the picture in one of the folders and it favorites it and organizes it at the same time. It even stacks the thumbnails on top of each other all scattered looking like a stack of papers. You can also hit the + at the far right to add additional favorites folders.

It's very slick and an awesome way for allowing users to favorite and organize on a website at the same time.

I'm looking for something just like this. So I was wondering if there is something in the jquery world that is similar. Or how I could pull this off with existing jquery scripts.

Keep in mind I have no javascript or programming knowledge at all.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI's draggable and droppable functionality would be the standard, but it will require some javascript programming.

[Info and examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)